# How do I know if add_subparsers() has already been called on a parser

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I'd like to create a function that will add a subcommand to a parser.

```py
def add_subparser(parser, command):
   sub_parsers = parser.add_subparsers('more commands')
   new_parser = sub_parsers.add_parser('free')
   return new_parser
```

It seems to me that the first line needs to check whether `parser` already has subparsers.  What is a good way to do that check?

(Side note: A nice future feature would be `get_subparsers` that returns a singleton.)

Comment: There's a `_subparsers` attribute if you're feeling brave

Comment: `try:...except SystemExit:` would do fine. But mostly: store the subparser and share it when you need to manage more commands.

Comment: I see it throwing a SystemExit

Comment: @RaySalemi: yes, it calls `parser.error()` which in turn raises `SystemExit`.

Comment: TBH that seems to be relying on implementation detail just as much as using the underscore attribute (it's not documented that you should only call it once nor that it raises a `SystemExit`).  The first thing `add_subparsers` does is check that attribute anyway.

Comment: This is why this really should be a `get_subparsers()` method that returns a singleton.  Then it would give me the action I need every time.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable addition for the argparse API to me, maybe make a PR for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `argparse.py` code.  The `add_subparsers` method starts with:

```
def add_subparsers(self, **kwargs):
    if self._subparsers is not None:
        self.error(_('cannot have multiple subparser arguments'))
```

and a bit later sets `self._subparsers` to a new value.

But if you don't want to look at `parser._subparsers` you could just wrap the new `add_subparses` command in a `try/except` block.

`add_subparsers` creates a positional `Action` with a special subparser subclass.  That's what we normally assign to a variable, and use in the next lines.  (as a side note, `add_argument` also returns an Action subclass object, the action that was just created).

It's instructive to set up a parser in an interactive session, and look at the objects that each command returns.  Most have a basic `str` method displaying some of the attributes.  As with any Python class object, you can explore the attributes in detail, even change some of them.

```
In [1]: import argparse                                                                                
In [2]: p = argparse.ArgumentParser()                                                                  
In [3]: sp = p.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')
```

`_actions` is a list of all Action class objects that were created.  Here there are two, the default `help` and the newly created subparser one.

```
In [4]: p._actions                                                                                     
Out[4]: 
[_HelpAction(option_strings=['-h', '--help'], dest='help', nargs=0, const=None, default='==SUPPRESS==', type=None, choices=None, help='show this help message and exit', metavar=None),
 _SubParsersAction(option_strings=[], dest='cmd', nargs='A...', const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=OrderedDict(), help=None, metavar=None)]

In [5]: type(p._actions[1])                                                                            
Out[5]: argparse._SubParsersAction
```

The `_subparsers` attribute is now set to an `ArgumentGroup`, in this case the first default one, the 'positionals'.

```
In [6]: p._subparsers                                                                                  
Out[6]: <argparse._ArgumentGroup at 0x7f3d8ede31d0>
In [7]: p._action_groups                                                                               
Out[7]: 
[<argparse._ArgumentGroup at 0x7f3d8ede31d0>,
 <argparse._ArgumentGroup at 0x7f3d8ede3cf8>]

In [9]: p.print_help()                                                                                 
usage: ipython3 [-h] {} ...

positional arguments:
  {}                    # the subparsers argument

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

And the error caused by trying to add another subparsers (caught in this case by `ipython`):

```
In [10]: sp = p.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')                                                             
usage: ipython3 [-h] {} ...
ipython3: error: cannot have multiple subparser arguments
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:3304: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
```

Comment: Thanks.Yes SystemExit is the thing to catch.